# mongoose is not creating db using mongoose.connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create new database using `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/imagesDB');` But is not creating. And please don't answer me saying that I need to add entries to it. I did it. Here's my full code.

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/imagesDB').then(() => {
console.log("Connected to Database");
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("Not Connected to Database ERROR! ", err);
});

const imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name: String,
    category: String,
    author: String,
    tag: String,
    imageURL: String
});

const Image = mongoose.model("Image", imageSchema);

const image = new Image({
    name: "Cat",
    category: "Animal",
    author:"Cat",
    tag: "Animals",
    imageURL: "https://cdn-media-2.freecodecamp.org/w1280/5f9c9a5d740569d1a4ca2531.jpg"
});

image.save();

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.send("Everything is running properly!");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server succesfully started on port 3000!");
});
```

Can you guys please test it for yourself? Does this creates a new database called imagesDB???

For me no, It is not working. I opened new tab in terminal and commanded mongo so it opened mongo client where i typed `show dbs` but it is not showing except these three admin, config and local.

I also wanna make it clear that mongo service is running, I did it by commanding `mongod --ipv6` in terminal.

Comment: Can you see the files in the db directory? Do you know which directori is db in?

Comment: I don't know that, I see some random named collection files and more in db folder but What do you mean??? btw is this code working for you?? and for more information, I got new PC so i installed MongoDB freshly, created data/db folders in c drive, add few lines so that i can easily call them using mongod and mongo command in terminal. this is my first code calling them. At first it didn't work for some unknown reason I'm using mongod --ipv6 to run MongoDB because if i run MongoDB using only `mongod` then mongoose is not able to connect. anyways here comes new problem. New DB is not creating.

Comment: `image.save();` is asynchronous.  Does it behave differently if you await it?

Comment: await image.save();
^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 .

Here's how it looks

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/imagesDB').then(() => {
console.log("Connected to Database");
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("Not Connected to Database ERROR! ", err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Mongoose Compass or Atlas?
Secondly, try doing it on VSCode terminal it will work then

Comment: I dont know about mongoose compass or atlas, I just did `npm i mongoose` anyways, while installing MongoDB Community edition, I unchecked MongoDB Compass.

Comment: I tried `node app.js` in VSCode Terminal. It did nothing different. BTW I use the hyper terminal.

Comment: Your database will be created in MongoDb Compass, you need to install it on your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to created your database named "imagesDB" in MongoDB Compass, or other GUI tool.

Comment: MongoDB Compass is not installed. I'm following udemy course, she said uncheck MongoDB Compass because it is not needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).